# adding suffix in URL is not working within request.clone?

Tags: string, angular, ecmascript-6

In Angular 4 I want to add base URL as a suffix in all HTTP request and along with modifying headers using interceptors but this is somehow not working as expected.

below is the relevant code and this is the [Angular reference](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080';

@Injectable()
export class NoopInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `${AUTH_PREFIX} ${this.authService.getToken()}`,
                another: 'header'
            },
            url: request.url.concat(BASE_URL)
        });
        console.log('new request: ', request);
        return next.handle(request);
    }
```

trial 1

trying to `concat` the URL directly just after request.cone()

```
 request.url.concat(BASE_URL);
```

trial 2

again clone the request and trying to add into the URL

```
const secureRequest = request.clone({
              url: request.url.concat(BASE_URL)
            });
```

none of the above is working? does Angular stop it or it's a wrong approach?

Comment: Do you get any error? Or just url not modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using concat correctly.

It should be

```
url: BASE_URL.concat(request.url)
```

and not the other way round